# Unity. Нужен ли мне временный конфигурационный файл для игры

Tags: unity3d

Сорян за такой кхм... заголовок, но ничего умного не лезло(как и всегда впрочем).

### Предисловие

Делаю игру в стиле добывалки(Craft The World). Save-файл подгружает параметры персонажа и сетку ресурсов(всякие руды, землю, песок и т.д.). Каждый ресурс имеет параметры. Например, стоимость, твёрдость и так далее... Есть параметр isKnown(известен ли ресурс игроку или нет), который можно изменить в строении Лаборатория.
Продолжаем. Save-файл также сохраняет те самые текущие параметры ресурсов(так как они будут меняться во время игры). При загрузке карты эти параметры соответственно подтягиваются.

### И так вопрос

Мне нужен дополнительный файл для этих конфигураций? Так как я не хочу изменять save-файл чисто из-за того что у ресурса поменялся параметр(с isKnown - false в isKnown - true), ведь помимо этого сохраняются параметры других объектов(карта большая и ресурсов много, нужно будет запомнить местоположение каждого). Или может мне нужно сделать это по другому?

Comment: Не проще сохранять твои memento структуры через `json` используя `PlayerPrefs`? И сохранение какого-нибудь `LabMementoData` не будет зависеть от других.

Comment: @Yaroslav, ну я это примерно и имел в виду, наверное. То-есть save-файл подгрузил все данные а дальше работает вот этот доп. конфиг. файл(через Json и в PlayerPrefs). Я так, правильно, понял?

Comment: @Yaroslav, также хотел задать вопрос по поводу шифровки save-файлов и этого доп. конфиг. файла. Нужна ли она? И если да то я работал ток с RSA. Как по мне нужно шифровать а то мало ли залезут и начитерят себе милионы гор. Как думаешь?

Comment: Зачем работать с файлами, если используешь `PlayerPrefs`? Шифровка по желанию, но по мне так это трата времени в никуда. Ну хочет миллион валюты, чем бы дитя не тешилось, таких людей ничтожно мало, покупатели из них паршивые и на общую покупку транзакций не влияют от слова совсем.

Comment: @Yaroslav, в Save-файл я буду сохранять по сути всю карту, в PlayerPrefs на сколько я читал уже так не получится. А доп.конфиг. файл может и не надо будет. Просто с save-файла подтягивать нужные данные в gameObject с скриптом tempData? Или же 30+ разных значений и структур в PlayerPrefs норма?